# Problems installing ntlk on Mac OSX

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install ntlk for a Django project. I followed the intstructions on NTLK's website, and I they worked because when I try to install again with pip, I get:

```
➜  Word_Maker git:(master) sudo pip install -U numpy
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages
Cleaning up...
➜  Word_Maker git:(master) sudo pip install -U pyyaml nltk
Requirement already up-to-date: pyyaml in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

However, when I do import ntlk from python3, I get:

```
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 16 2013, 23:39:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 37
    except IOError, ex:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
              ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

import numpy works, however. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: `nltk` in ... 
And you're trying to `import ntlk`. Try using `import nltk`. I.e. check the spelling

Comment: Wow, really silly mistake. Now, I get this error though:  Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 16 2013, 23:39:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 37
    except IOError, ex:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you made a spelling mistake:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages
```

And you're trying to `import ntlk`. Try using `import nltk`.

As for the import error, the following from their website:

> NLTK requires Python versions 2.6-2.7. (A version supporting Python 3 is available at http://nltk.org/nltk3-alpha/).

So NLTK does not (yet) support python 3.3 fully.

First remove NLTK using pip: `sudo pip uninstall nltk`

Then download the source. And install using `sudo python setup.py install`

And try again. Be aware this is an alpha, so expect some methods to randomly throw errors or generate unexpected output.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have this error after fixing the spelling, the issue is that PyPI is installing an older NLTK package (2.x). Check this by looking at the first message in the terminal immediately after your run `sudo pip install nltk`.

To install the latest version of NLTK (3.x) that is compatible with Python 3, first `sudo pip uninstall nltk`.

Then use:

```
sudo pip install nltk==3.0.0b2
```

The latest version number is found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk

Comment: This should really be the top answer

Comment: Hard coded version may not be a lasting solution though.  Perhaps a full install with -U is a better more time independent solution of this problem.  Also noted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the versions of dependent packages may cause issues.  The main issue is old, but I found a slightly different problem when using the parser - which internally was going into scipy.  Solved using:

```
pip3 uninstall nltk scipy matplotlib 
pip3 install -U nltk scipy matplotlib
```